# Cypress chrome not pausing at debugger statement

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following code in the test:

```
it('shows correct language', () => {
  cy.visit('/product/my product');
  cy.changeLanguage('English');
  cy.get('[data-test=attribute-name]').should(
    (elements) => {
      console.log('this shows in console', elements);
      alert('But it wont break!!!!!!!!!!');//this alert shows
      debugger;//never breaks here
    },
  );
});
```

Started cypress with `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open` then I run the test in the cypress window, that opens chrome and I open the dev tools manually (don't know how tell cypress to open chrome with devtools open).

It shows the message in the console and shows the alert but never actually breaks. In the `sources` tab the "Deactivate breakpoints" is not set so breakpoints are active.

Manually set the breakpoint and then click the "Run all test" button after the first run will pause on the manually set breakpoint but ignores the `debugger` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've managed to solve the issue you're having

Rather than using `debugger`, you can use `cy.debug()`. But for it to work, you NEED to have your debugger/console open when running the test.

Check out this page for more info: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/debug.html

Comment: It is pausing now but it pauses in `http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js` and that's nowhere near where I want it to pause in the test. Tried to step out but after 25 times I'm still in cypress code and not in my test. Normal debug statements and breakpoints in code are still completely ignored. Could this have something to do with cypress having to rebuild the code and/or use source maps? If I put console.log statements in there I see them in the console and clicking on it takes me to the exact line the log is (in original code, not the transpiled version)

Comment: @HMR did you figure it out?